# Convergence in $l^{2}(\mathbb{Z})$ for $c_{n}(f)$ if $n \in \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

Does Convergence in $l^{2}(\mathbb{Z})$ for $c_{n}(f)$ if $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ means, $$\sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty}|c_{n}(f)|^2 < \infty, $$
i.e. the summation extends from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, it looks so strange for me, but I think this is exactly the meaning (similar to Bessel`s inequality), am I right?

Comment: Yes that is the meaning I think. This question seems to lack some context. What is $f$? What is $c_n(f)$?

Comment: I think the information you want is not necessary, I am just asking about convergence in $l^{2}(\mathbb{Z})$, because in Kreyszig (introduction to functional analysis ) the summation extends from $n=1$ to $n=\infty$ @User8128

Comment: It is difficult to answer completely/correctly without knowing what is being asked. A sequence ${x_n}$ is in $\ell^2 (\mathbb Z)$ if and only if $$\sum^{\infty}_{n=-\infty} \lvert x_n \rvert^2 < \infty.$$ This is the definition of $\ell^2(\mathbb Z)$. However, it is still unclear to me what is being asked. What is $f$? Why do you have $c_n(f)$? Typically $\ell^2(\mathbb Z)$ is a space of sequences and typically $f$ is a function. This is my confusion.

Comment: $f \in L^{2}([-L,L])$ and $c_{n}(f)$ is the same as the one in the question you answered that needs extra condition which is $f$ is periodic or compactly supported. but in the book called " Introductory Functional Analysis with application" by Erwin Kreyszig, the summation extends from 1 to $\infty$ which is different from your previous comment, do you know why ? if yes please explain to me ?@User8128